# Create a multi-index data-frame

Tags: python, multi-index

I have the following code to create a multi-indexed data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define the data
data = {
    ('rf', 'wv_pretrained'): (0.7392722279437006, 0.7412604086615894),
    ('rf', 'wv_custom'): (0.7746309646412634, 0.7762235207436783),
    ('rf', 'glove_pretrained'): (0.7411603158256094, 0.7427841615992615),
    ('rf', 'spacy_pretrained'): (0.731719876416066, 0.7338888018745795),
    ('rf', 'sent_trf'): (0.7229660144181257, 0.7242986991569383),
    ('rf', 'bert_trf'): (0.7126673532440783, 0.7139687043942123),
    ('rf', 'gpt_trf'): (0.7351527634740816, 0.7369294342385289),
    ('rf', 'tfidf'): (0.6920700308959835, 0.6878065672519817),
    ('Logistic_Regression', 'wv_pretrained'): (0.7392722279437006, 0.7412604086615894),
    ('Logistic_Regression', 'wv_custom'): (0.7746309646412634, 0.7762235207436783),
    ('Logistic_Regression', 'glove_pretrained'): (0.7411603158256094, 0.7427841615992615),
    ('Logistic_Regression', 'spacy_pretrained'): (0.731719876416066, 0.7338888018745795),
    ('Logistic_Regression', 'sent_trf'): (0.7229660144181257, 0.7242986991569383),
    ('Logistic_Regression', 'bert_trf'): (0.7126673532440783, 0.7139687043942123),
    ('Logistic_Regression', 'gpt_trf'): (0.7351527634740816, 0.7369294342385289),
    ('Logistic_Regression', 'tfidf'): (0.6920700308959835, 0.6878065672519817)
}

# Create the multi-index
algos = ['rf', 'Logistic_Regression']
embeddings = ['wv_pretrained', 'wv_custom', 'glove_pretrained', 'spacy_pretrained', 'sent_trf', 'bert_trf', 'gpt_trf', 'tfidf']
eval_metrics = ['accuracy', 'f1_score']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([algos, embeddings], names=['algos', 'Embedding'])
columns = pd.Index(eval_metrics, name='Metrics')

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=columns)
df
```

But i am getting no numerical values. Screen shot of the error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried using `('rf', 'wv_pretrained'): np.array([0.7392722279437006, 0.7412604086615894])`  but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do

```py
algos = ['rf', 'Logistic_Regression']
embeddings = ['wv_pretrained', 'wv_custom', 'glove_pretrained', 'spacy_pretrained', 'sent_trf', 'bert_trf', 'gpt_trf', 'tfidf']
eval_metrics = ['accuracy', 'f1_score']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([algos, embeddings], names=['algos', 'Embedding'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=eval_metrics).T#.reindex(idx)
```

```
print(df)

                                      accuracy  f1_score
algos               Embedding
rf                  wv_pretrained     0.739272  0.741260
                    wv_custom         0.774631  0.776224
                    glove_pretrained  0.741160  0.742784
                    spacy_pretrained  0.731720  0.733889
                    sent_trf          0.722966  0.724299
                    bert_trf          0.712667  0.713969
                    gpt_trf           0.735153  0.736929
                    tfidf             0.692070  0.687807
Logistic_Regression wv_pretrained     0.739272  0.741260
                    wv_custom         0.774631  0.776224
                    glove_pretrained  0.741160  0.742784
                    spacy_pretrained  0.731720  0.733889
                    sent_trf          0.722966  0.724299
                    bert_trf          0.712667  0.713969
                    gpt_trf           0.735153  0.736929
                    tfidf             0.692070  0.687807
```